# How to make the following syntax simpler using if else and looping functions in R?

Tags: r, loops, if-statement

I have a series of if else statements and want to make it simpler by adding a looping function. My code looks the following :

```
n=length(Tabel_FLR$fuzzifikasi)
peramalan=array(NA,dim=c(n))
for(i in 1:n){
peramalan[i+1]=if(Tabel_FLR$fuzzifikasi[i]=="A1"){print(yA1)}
else if(Tabel_FLR$fuzzifikasi[i]=="A2"){print(yA2)}
else if(Tabel_FLR$fuzzifikasi[i]=="A3"){print(yA3)}
else if(Tabel_FLR$fuzzifikasi[i]=="A4"){print(yA4)}
else if(Tabel_FLR$fuzzifikasi[i]=="A5"){print(yA5)}
else if(Tabel_FLR$fuzzifikasi[i]=="A6"){print(yA6)}
else if(Tabel_FLR$fuzzifikasi[i]=="A7"){print(yA7)}
else if(Tabel_FLR$fuzzifikasi[i]=="A8"){print(yA8)}
else if(Tabel_FLR$fuzzifikasi[i]=="A9"){print(yA9)}
else if(Tabel_FLR$fuzzifikasi[i]=="A10"){print(yA10)}
else if(Tabel_FLR$fuzzifikasi[i]=="A11"){print(yA11)}
else if(Tabel_FLR$fuzzifikasi[i]=="A12"){print(yA12)}
else if(Tabel_FLR$fuzzifikasi[i]=="A13"){print(yA13)}
else if(Tabel_FLR$fuzzifikasi[i]=="A14"){print(yA14)}
else if(Tabel_FLR$fuzzifikasi[i]=="A15"){print(yA15)}
else if(Tabel_FLR$fuzzifikasi[i]=="A16"){print(yA16)}
else if(Tabel_FLR$fuzzifikasi[i]=="A17"){print(yA17)}
else if(Tabel_FLR$fuzzifikasi[i]=="A18"){print(yA18)}
else if(Tabel_FLR$fuzzifikasi[i]=="A19"){print(yA19)}
else if(Tabel_FLR$fuzzifikasi[i]=="A20"){print(yA20)}
else if(Tabel_FLR$fuzzifikasi[i]=="A21"){print(yA21)}
else if(Tabel_FLR$fuzzifikasi[i]=="A22"){print(yA22)}
else if(Tabel_FLR$fuzzifikasi[i]=="A23"){print(yA23)}
}
```

Any advice would be great, Thanks!

Comment: What are `yA1, yA2..`? are they variables or string literals? ie is it `print("yA1")` or `print(yA1)`? if its the first one, then simply do `paste0("y", Tabel_FLR$fuzzifikasi)`

Comment: They are variables that have been defined in the previous code

Comment: 1) Can you post sample `yA1`, `yA2`?; 2) It's a bad idea to have the `yA?` in the global environment, put them in a list or data.frame; 3) Then, maybe something like `A_vec <- paste0("A", 1:23); i <- match(Tabel_FLR$fuzzifikasi, A_vec); print(yA_list[[i]])`.

Comment: What @RuiBarradas says: you maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.  Also, an `if` statement returns nothing.  So `peramalan[i+1]=if...` assigns `NULL`.  In other words, it does nothing.  What do you intend to assign to `peramalan[i+1]`?

Comment: `peramalan[i+1]` will not work correctly on the last iteration of your `for` loop, since it is only defined up until `peramalan[n]`. It will not error, but it is guaranteed to return `NA`.

Comment: Having a loop that iterates over each value in one column and merely `print`s something to the console hardly seems like a functional component of data import, munging, etc. If your intent is to do "something more" with the data, then it is possible that what you want to do can be done on the vector as a whole; if your intent is to return another vector of values based on the values of that column, then there are much easier (to read and maintain) methods than that, perhaps a merge/join (more help may be required here).

Comment: Bottom line, I suspect that this is a bit of an "X/Y problem", where you believe you need to solve "X" to get what you need, but really "Y" is the real issue. We can help with both, but our recommendations tend to encourage you to be more efficient in how you do things. Welcome to SO, Amsal Esa Hasana!

Answer (score 0):

You can consider the following approach :

```
yA1 <- 3
yA2 <- 5
yA3 <- 9

vec_Val <- c("A1", "A2", "A3")
nb_Val <- length(vec_Val)

for(i in 1 : nb_Val)
{
  eval(parse(text = paste0("print(y", vec_Val[i], ")")))
}

[1] 3
[1] 5
[1] 9
```